# When i render an image some if it turns black how do i fix this?

Tags: rendering

Everytime i render an image some if the render turns a little black is there a fix to this? If so please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enough lighting, and if you aren't using actual lights, you can check "environmental lighting" under the world tab on the right of standard view (one with the globe icon). If none of these are your reason maybe include some more details in your post (pictures of the issue/.blend file). Hope I helped.